# Bulk update to mySQL work too slow

Tags: mysql, csv

currenly i use a simple code to update gender in my mysql

my code:

```
    <?php
ini_set('max_execution_time', 30000); 
    $row = 0;
    if (($handle = fopen("list.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
            $num = count($data);

            for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            $name = $data[0];   
            $gender = $data[1]; 
            }
    // connect to db
    mysql_connect("***", "***", "***") or die("Connection Failed");
    mysql_select_db("info")or die("Connection Failed");
        $query = "UPDATE data SET gender = '$gender' WHERE fname = '$name'";
        if(mysql_query($query)){
                        $row++;
    echo "$row: ";      
    echo '<font color="RED">' . $name  . '</font> <br>';  

        }


        }
        fclose($handle);
    }
 ?>
```

code works but very slow,
can process up to 10k records per 1 hour and its too slow for me

**can someone give me an idea what to do with it to increase speed**

Comment: What @obe wrote, and check that you have an index on `fname` column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are re-connecting to the DB in every single *while* iteration. Take the *mysql_connect* and *mysql_select_db* calls out of the *while* loop...

Comment: ive set out the while loop mysql_connect and mysql_select_db calls but still work very slow. Also, my fname have an index

Comment: How far is the MySQL server? Is it in the same network or at a different facility..?

Comment: server is on localhost and run script only from main PC with localhost

Comment: And you're sure you have an index on *fname*? ~2.5 updates per second does sound pretty slow...

Comment: you need an index on the *fname* column in addition to the id column (unless *fname* IS the id column...)

Comment: yes, this was the problem, ive added index to fname and now works much faster.Thank for your help and sorry i did not understand your idea at first